# Is it possible to enable the standard Orbeon submit button in the example applications

Tags: orbeon

Orbeon is providing some examples that can be run easily. For example I can run in my computer `http://localhost:8080/orbeon/xforms-wizard-pfc/` that does not seems to be a form created using the Form Builder. I was always using the form builder as a starting point but the last days I was paying more attention on these examples for learning a little more.

In this case, it is a form that is using a flow with different questions that are defined in different XHTML files. I like this idea for using it in very big forms.

All this examples, are using custom submit buttons with its own actions, but none of them are saving the result into database except an example that uses a rest service of 'exists' database (I have configured my Orbeon datasource to use MySQL).

I have tested that some configuration of the form runner (`properties-local.xml`) affects also these examples such as changing the date format, therefore maybe it is also possible to enable the standard submit button that already I have configured and save the forms into database for later be shown in the summary page of the Form Runner. But I am not able to do this with these examples using the property `oxf.fr.detail.send.success.uri.<app>.<form>`. Specially, because no application is defined in the example.

There is any way to, for example, save the submitted data of these "XForms applications" using the datasource of Orbeon to save to MySQL database as when using a form created by the Form Builder?

Or I need to use rest services to send data to a custom application that does all this kind of work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you're referring to (`xforms-wizard-pfc`), along with similar examples, are written in "plain XForms". In the other side, when you create a form in Form Builder, the result goes through Form Builder, that adds a number of features on top of XForms, like persistence or the error summary (with a number of them implemented, at least in part, in XForms).

All those features that are part of Form Runner are not designed to be used on their own, so you can't easily, say, "just use the Form Runner persistence" in one of your forms. This means that you most likely need to decide whether you're better off using the whole of Form Runner, or no Form Runner at all, and just write plain XForms.

Comment: Ok, more or less the think I have supossed. But the think that is confusing me is if I change some configuration of the Form Runner (date format) is still affecting this examples, therefore I was wondering if also some other properties can be added to this example. To sum up, if I want to use plain XForms and persist into database, then probably I need to write a small application with a rest service that does the persistence actions.